# Is there a way to set the css class of panels/tables/etc in ActiveAdmin

Tags: activeadmin

It would be great to color the table or elements in a table differently if based on attributes of the record(s).

For examples, I have a table of different media, and I want to style the show table for streaming differently than for DVDs. Likewise, on the index page, carry over that styling for different rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `id:` and `class:` to any Arbre tag or component, eg. `panel(id: 'streaming')`. You can then add relevant styling to `active_admin.css`.